# Does dotConnect for SQLite support Mono?

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, devart, dotconnect

Does the dotConnect provider for SQLite from Devart support Mono? Google seems to say it does, but their own compatibility page says it does not.

I'm looking to use Code First on Mono with SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its own page says it does not, there must be some pieces missing. But you can always have a test on your own. Maybe your application happens to use only the compatible part of it.

This applies to many existing products, such as Microsoft Unity. They are all reported by MoMA as not fully compatible with Mono/Linux, but you can still use them on Mono in some cases.

Comment: The reverse is also true: not everything tat MoMA reports to work realy do work but it does give some indication.